# Trim and WhiteSpaceTrimmer

Tags: javascript, trim

I face One problem in JavaScript .What it is now I am using dojo componets in jsp page. So I changed trim function into WhiteSpaceTrimmer function. But it is working in mozilla Firefox not in IE8.in i.e. shows one `error:var ItemLot=(temp2[1].trim()+"*"+temp2[5].trim());` not a method.

Here if we remove trim function it is working but my final step takes only trim value.

Comment: _"I face One problem in javascript"_ - Only one? You're doing better than me.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of IE do not support the `String.trim` method.  You can add this code to your startup code for your page to add the trim method to the String object in case it doesn't exist:

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
  };
}
```

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Answer (score 0):

Dojo provides methods `dojo.trim()` and `dojo.string.trim()` which will use the native String.prototype.trim() method if available, and provide an implementation in JS if not, much like what @jfriend00 suggests.  If you're using Dojo and you need to support older browsers, you might as well use these.  Pass in the string as the only argument.